# Example: Objective C method alongside a php method

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c

I am very used to javascript and php programing, and I just jumped into programing Objective C.  After working with it for a few weeks, the methods still confused me, as to how it is passing params, and how the methods are named.

Since I am used to php, I am used to seeing:

```
function myFunc($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4) {
   return FALSE;
}
```

Could someone show me how this would be written in Objective C, so that I can get used to writing methods that have parameters?

Comment: Related question: [Method Syntax in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-(int) myFuncWithParam1: (int)param1 andParam2: (int)param2 andParam3: (int)param3 andParam4: (int)param4 {
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, it's not a good example, because in Objective-C method signatures are supposed to look more appealing to the human and make sense. Like `[thingamajig panicWithIntensity: 12 andEagerness: 126]`. But you're free to do it differently, of course.

Comment: So, basically the method name is broken up into pieces?

Comment: @Nic exactly! It's a convenient way to remember what each parameter is supposed to do.