# What are the exact names for the components of an argument?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

Example: I have this Objective-C code:

```
+(NSString*)stringWithString:(NSString*)string;
```

**String:** is the *name of the argument*?

**NSString*** is the *data type of the argument*?

for the last part, **string** I'm not sure. It's somewhat a name too. But what's the exact term?

Here's an example from the apple docs:

---

```
+ (id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date
```

*seconds*
The number of seconds to add to date. Use a negative argument to specify a date and time before date.

*date*
The date.

---

Obviously they're looking at the variable when referencing the arguments, not the name part in front of the datatype-brackets. I was always wondering how to name this thing correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Method Syntax in Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c)

Comment: what you want to know about the syntax or naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `+` shows that it is class function you can access it by the class not the object.
first `(NSString*)` shows it returns an string then  `stringWithString` this is the name
and after that `(NSString*)`is the argument type.

and finally `string` is the argument which use as local parameter for the function.

Name of the function , variables and classes follow a naming convention for easy understanding about the code.