# iPhone SDK - Call Objective C function

Tags: objective-c, parameter-passing

i would like to create a function called "playSound" with one (but later two parameters - one, which is the filename and one, which is the musictype (mp3,...))

but i cant get the paramter working in my function...please help me

here's my code

```
    //
//  MainView.m
//
//  Created by Christopher Fuchs on 26.01.11.
//  Copyright 2011 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MainView.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation MainView

void playSound(char filename){
 UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Mein Alert" message:filename delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 [alert show];
 [alert release];

}

- (IBAction)PlayFatGuyWalking:(id)sender {

 playSound(@"MusicFile");

}
@end
```

For now, i just added an alert instead of the playing sound framework
the paramater is called "filename" and should be called as message of the alert

thanks in advance

greez

Comment: This has been covered many times, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c ,
 even Wikipedia describes the differences between C functions and Obj-C methods: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages

You need to change the prototype for playSound to Obj-C syntax. Moreover, the @".." literal is for a NSString, not a char (nor char*, which is probably what you meant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this line:

```
void playSound(char filename)
```

into this:

```
void playSound(NSString *filename)
```

The @ "foo" construction says "this is an NSString".

Also, if you want to keep it a C function, you might want to move it out of the @implementation block.

You will find that virtually everything asking for a string in Cocoa will want an NSString, and not a char *.

Oh yeah, and the (char filename) won't work in plain C either, that a single byte variable, not a pointer to a potential string.

Comment: If you really want it to be a C function, not an Objective-C method, you also need to move it outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)playSound:(NSString *)filename {
  // method body
}

// calling
[self playSound:@"MusicFile"];
```