# how do i write the name of a method with multiple parameters in the .h file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iOS. I have defined the following method in a .m file and need to add its name to the .h file.

```
-(Boolean) addBookFromArrayOne:(Book*)bookOne bookTwo:(Book*)bookTwo mergeByThisField:(NSString*)field sortDescending:(Boolean)
```

This post [Method Syntax in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c) was very helpful in learning the Objective C method syntax. The answer

> in Objective-C, the name of a method is composed of all of the
>   portions of the declaration that are not arguments and types. This
>   method's name would therefore be: pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:

was particularly helpful.

But it does not show how to generalize to multiple parameters.

I took a guess at the syntax in the header file but am clearly getting it wrong:

```
@property Boolean addBookFromArrayOne:bookTwo:mergeByThisField:sortDescending;
```

Can somebody show me how to define this method name in the header file?

Comment: Arguments to a property? Doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just copy method declaration from implemetation to header**

```
-(Boolean) addBookFromArrayOne:(Book*)bookOne bookTwo:(Book*)bookTwo mergeByThisField:(NSString*)field sortDescending:(Boolean)desc;
```

Comment: That's not a method declaration. That's a method implementation. BIG difference.

Comment: It is example, also fix method syntax

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a property to declare a method; to declare a method in your header file just write:

```
-(Boolean) addBookFromArrayOne:(Book*)bookOne bookTwo:(Book*)bookTwo mergeByThisField:(NSString*)field sortDescending:(Boolean)descending;
```

Comment: You should give the last parameter a name.

Comment: Fixed syntax, grammar and terminology. You owe me $10.