# use of titleForState and initWithFormat in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, label

I am a mere beginner in iPhone Programming. I have seen this code in a tutorial which I didn't understand what does it means. I am confused about keywords such as `titleForState` and `initWithFormat`.

Can anyone help me to understand the meaning and importance of this syntax.

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed: (id)sender {
    NSString *title = [sender **titleForState**:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *newText = [[NSString alloc] **initWithFormat**:
             @"%@ button pressed.", title];
    statusText.text = newText;//statustext is a label 
    [newText release];
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initwithFormat` allows you to modify a string by adding a variable's value to it, you can add as many variables as you like but you have to add the correct symbol for the correct primitive type. Here are some examples

```
  NSString *thisIsAString = @"String";
  float thisIsAFloat = 13.9f;
  NSString *strFormat = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"This is a %@, this is a %f float", thisIsAString, thisIsAFloat];
  NSLog(@"%@", strFormat);
```

This will produce the output `This is a String, this is a 13.9f float` notice the `float` and the `NSString` value have replaced the symbols.

The `titleForState` is getting the title of an object that has that method. This will return the title for lets say a UIButton that has a title of "Press" for `UIControlStateNormal` so the value "Press" will be entered into the `NSString` title. Not though that not everything in sender has the method `titleForState` the reason this will show up is because sender is a primitive type of `id` this will cause and error if something is sent that hasn't got `titleForState` and your app will crash.