# C++ style function headers in Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have a function that I want to declare and use in a typical C++ style within a class.

Hypothetical example definition from .mm file:

```
float MyClass::getRectArea(float width, float height){
  return width*height;
}
```

How can I declare this function in the objective-C class header/.h file?

```
@interface MyClass

//???

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just write it as a function, just like you would in C++ — only it wouldn't be part of the class, because functions aren't part of classes in Objective-C. If you wanted it to be part of a class, you could make it a class method along the lines of:

```
+ (float)rectAreaWithWidth:(float)width height:(float)height {
    return width * height;
}
```

I would probably not make it an instance method, as suggested in another answer, because it really doesn't have anything to do with a particular object value — it's a pure function of its arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as

```
-(float)getRectArea:(float)width getheight:(float)height;
```

Then in the .m file, you can define it as

```
-(float)getRectArea:(float)width getheight:(float)height {
     return width*height;
 }
```

You can call it as follows

```
float area = [self getRectArea:5.0 getheight:4.0];
```

For more details and explanation see [Method Syntax in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

If you want MyClass to be a C++ object then you would create the header as you normally would with C++.

MyClass.h

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    float getRectArea(float width, float height);
};
```