# int value not passing, unrecognized selector sent to instance Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: objective-c, exception, unrecognized-selector, nsinteger, nsexception

I'm trying to pass two integer values between different files but getting a error as mentioned in title.

Error at this line:      - (NSString *) lookup: (NSString *)in  get:(int)dictio     get1:(int)dictio1;

Error File:

```
2014-02-05 13:27:48.019 MaisOui[4556:70b] Value of d: 10   d1: 0 

2014-02-05 13:27:49.496 MaisOui[4556:70b] Value of d: 10   d1: 10 

2014-02-05 13:27:56.405 MaisOui[4556:70b] -[MaisOuiDictionary lookup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c44d30
2014-02-05 13:27:56.409 MaisOui[4556:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MaisOuiDictionary lookup:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c44d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173f5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c28b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017dc903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0172f90b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0172f4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   MaisOui                             0x00003299 -[MaisOuiViewController textFieldShouldReturn:] + 313
    6   UIKit                               0x0091761f -[UITextField keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:] + 357
    7   UIKit                               0x004054f3 -[UIKeyboardImpl callShouldInsertText:] + 271
    8   UIKit                               0x0040f7d0 -[UIKeyboardImpl addWordTerminator:afterSpace:elapsedTime:executionContext:] + 63
    9   UIKit                               0x0040f2ca -[UIKeyboardImpl completeAcceptCandidateBeforeAddingInput:executionContext:] + 1668
    10  UIKit                               0x0040eba6 __60-[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:withFlags:executionContext:]_block_invoke + 53
    11  UIKit                               0x0093ee7e -[UIKeyboardTaskExecutionContext returnExecutionToParent] + 254
    12  UIKit                               0x0041244b -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptCurrentCandidateIfSelectedWithExecutionContext:] + 250
    13  UIKit                               0x0040eb69 -[UIKeyboardImpl addInputString:withFlags:executionContext:] + 451
    14  UIKit                               0x0040da2f -[UIKeyboardImpl handleStringInput:withFlags:executionContext:] + 248
    15  UIKit                               0x0041bc1f -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyWithString:forKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 633
    16  UIKit                               0x0041b766 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:executionContext:] + 1808
    17  UIKit                               0x0041afbf __33-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:]_block_invoke + 51
    18  UIKit                               0x0093f3c8 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 402
    19  UIKit                               0x0093fa6f -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue addTask:] + 144
    20  UIKit                               0x0041af84 -[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyEvent:] + 227
    21  UIKit                               0x0024440b -[UIApplication _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 330
    22  UIKit                               0x0038afa4 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    23  UIKit                               0x0038afa4 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    24  UIKit                               0x0038afa4 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    25  UIKit                               0x0038afa4 -[UIResponder(Internal) _handleKeyUIEvent:] + 59
    26  UIKit                               0x002442ba -[UIApplication handleKeyUIEvent:] + 84
    27  UIKit                               0x0024425e -[UIApplication handleKeyHIDEvent:] + 458
    28  UIKit                               0x0022c07c _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2954
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x016c883f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x016c81cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x016e529e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    32  CoreFoundation                      0x016e4ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    33  CoreFoundation                      0x016e48db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    34  GraphicsServices                    0x036e49e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    35  GraphicsServices                    0x036e4809 GSEventRun + 104
    36  UIKit                               0x00230d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    37  MaisOui                             0x00002c5d main + 141
    38  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d7d70d start + 1
    39  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

---

```
#import "MaisOuiAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MaisOuiAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

---

From file to pass:

```
int d=0;
int d1=0;
```

File passed to:

```
@interface MaisOuiDictionary : NSObject

- (NSString *) lookup: (NSString *) in;
- (int) dic : (int) dictio;
- (int) dic1 : (int ) dictio1;


@end



- (NSString *) lookup: (NSString *)in  get:(int)dictio     get1:(int)dictio1;
{


  //  if(dictio==10 && dictio1==10)
    {
    NSString *rv = [self.wordsE_S objectForKey: in];
    if ( !rv )
        return @"*** no translation ***";

    return rv;
    }
 //   return @"**nothing**";
}
```

Can someone tell me where I wrong. I have tried changing all values to int * and NSInteger *, but still getting the same error.

Comment: can you add the full error in your question?

Comment: None of this makes any sense. First, post the exact and complete error message. Second - which line of code is causing the problem?

Comment: Edited, please have a look now.

Comment: Given the crash log, please post your implementation of `textFieldShouldReturn`

Comment: What do you mean by textFieldShouldReturn ?

Comment: `5 MaisOui 0x00003299 -[MaisOuiViewController textFieldShouldReturn:] + 313` suggests you've implemented this, and you're calling `lookup:` on an inappropriate object within it.

Comment: I might be totally off here but is `- (NSString *) lookup: (NSString *)in  get:(int)dictio get1:(int)dictio1;` supposed to be implementation of the function lookup defined in the interface? In that case why is there a semi-colon at the end and why does the definition not match with the lookup defined in the interface.

Comment: I'd wager the compiler is reporting warnings about an "incomplete implementation" and that the "method definition for 'lookup:' not found". You should heed those warnings, as they're warning you of the problem about the `@implementation` not matching the `@interface` which can lead to these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2):

You've implemented this method

```
- (NSString*)lookup:(NSString*)in get:(int)dictio get1:(int)diction;
```

...but it looks like you're trying to call this method (that has been defined in your interface)

```
- (NSString*)lookup:(NSString*)in;
```

Because the implementation of `lookup:` doesn't exist, you're getting an exception thrown. You need to either:

1. Declare `lookup:get:get1:` in your interface, and call that in `textFieldShouldReturn:` instead of `lookup:`
2. Implement `lookup:` in your implementation

It all boils down to you calling a method that doesn't exist. Clarification on method naming in Objective C can be found here: [Method Syntax in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683211/method-syntax-in-objective-c)